# Editor's name is inactive

Tags: discussion, editing, user-accounts, deleted-accounts, edit-history

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380687/zero-dimensional-ideals-in-polynomial-rings), a question [was edited](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/380687/revisions). But editors name is inactive; I mean it's written in gray and one can not click on it. Why?
Thank you.

Comment: The account has since been deleted.

Comment: No. it's not. you can find it in "USERS" section

Comment: That's a [different user](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/121097/user26857) who has chosen to make their screen name 26857. The *unique* identifier is the string of numbers - the first account is 26857, the second is 121097. Only one can be altered by the user.

Comment: Thank you; can you explain a little more  about "The unique identifier is the string of numbers - the first account is 26857, the second is 121097"? can you please post a complete answer?

Comment: The string of numbers correlates with the creation of the account, and is roughly sequential. You were (very roughly) around the 133000th account created, while I have something around 297000.

Comment: Thank you again...